# C# - Searching items in a big list

Tags: c#, search, large-data, collect, autodesk-navisworks

**Hey everyone,**

I'm developing a plugin for Autodesk Navisworks: User types in textboxes the name of the category type, property type, and keyword, then clicks the Custom button which search and collect the matching items from a file tree.

The following code works for a "small" file tree (hundreds of items), but when I launch the search for the whole file (containing thousands of items) the program freezes and  it uses all available physical memory. I would like to know how I could improve my code so it can deal with bigger files?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api;
using NavisworksApp = Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application;

namespace ClashPlugin.Ctr
{
    public partial class ClashPlugin : UserControl
    {
        public ClashPlugin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnParentChanged(e);
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private static string GetPropValue(DataProperty prop)
        {
            try
            {
                return prop.Value.IsDisplayString ? prop.Value.ToDisplayString() : prop.Value.ToString().Split(':')[1];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "Prop Error";
            }
        }

        private void btCustom_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Find all
            try
            {
                var result = new List<ModelItem>();

                foreach (var item in NavisworksApp.ActiveDocument.CurrentSelection.SelectedItems)
                {
                    var cat = item.DescendantsAndSelf.Where(i => i.PropertyCategories.FindCategoryByDisplayName(tbCatName.Text) != null);

                    var pro = cat.Where(m => m.PropertyCategories.FindCategoryByDisplayName(tbCatName.Text).Properties.FindPropertyByDisplayName(tbPropName.Text) != null);

                    result.AddRange(pro.Where(m => GetPropValue(m.PropertyCategories.FindCategoryByDisplayName(tbCatName.Text).Properties.FindPropertyByDisplayName(tbPropName.Text)).Contains(tbValueName.Text)));
                }
                
                NavisworksApp.ActiveDocument.CurrentSelection.Clear();                
                NavisworksApp.ActiveDocument.CurrentSelection.AddRange(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: have you considered using a database?

Comment: I edited what's the crash.
Unfortunately I do not have any exception message when the program freezes.

@NavjotSingh I'm quite new to this language so I don't know much about how it works. It would be helpful if it could deal with any current big list.

Comment: Try using a database and do the filtering of the data in the database rather than in program memory. If it is a desktop application you can consider using `SQLite`.

Comment: If it is a crash, you can see the call stack in the Application event log.

Comment: @Kaveesh Ok thx then it's not a crash , nothing comes out from the App event log

Comment: @MatthewWatson It only freezes and goes into an infinite loop. (Not really a crash then)

Comment: @Nick I answered you above.

Comment: Can you access the NavisworksApp data on a pure data level, for example the NavisworksApp database? One problem in your code surely is that you run a very long lasting query on the UI thread - which results in the impression of a freeze - even if it returns after a while.
The other is that you are working on data that is UI bound (`NavisworksApp.ActiveDocument.CurrentSelection.SelectedItems`). This tends to run slowly since it usually has a lot of UI bindings and event listeners.
If you'd run the same query logic a) in a Task/background thread and b) in "the model" it could potentially help.

Comment: I solved the problem! What you said about very long query through Visual Studio and with the UI thread helped. I don't know if I did what @lidqy suggested but it's pretty close as I directly called the 'find' function from NavisworksApp with the Search method. The software itself easily deals with big files. Here's a link that explains how it works for further similar problems: https://apidocs.co/apps/navisworks/2018/87317537-2911-4c08-b492-6496c82b3edd.htm
Thanks all